# How to write a bibtex style for my university?

Tags: bibtex

My university uses [Harvard UTS](http://www.lib.uts.edu.au/help/referencing/harvard-uts-referencing-guide) referencing system. I have to write an engineering report and my references are more than 50. I think if I do all 50 references by hands, it takes too much time.  So I would like to write a package and a bibtex style to ease the writing of references. Unfortunately I am not much familiar with bibtex. Can someone please help me writing a bibtex style file?

Comment: The simplest way would be to use `custom-bib`. Open a terminal (command line), and then type `latex makebst`. Then follow the prompt. It will asks question about how you want to format the reference. At the end you get a suitable BibTeX style.

Comment: By the way there is a `harvard` package, and a few `bst` styles `apsr, `agsm`, `dcu`, `kluwer`. You might try with them first, and use `custom-bib` if they are not suitable for you.

Comment: Your university should already be suggesting a specific bibliography style. Would the registrar's office, or a similar office, be able to furnish this information?

Comment: You can create your biblatex style. You will find a lot of inspiration here at TeX.sx. Eg.: [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles)

Answer (score 3):

It's always the best using a tool to create the bibliography. The standard mechanism for LaTeX is

1. Saving the information in a file with the extension `bib`.
2. Using BibTeX or `biblatex`/`biber` to create the bibliography.

The complete steps and the interaction are well explained in most common introductions.

Using the standard compilation BibTeX you can use a predefined style. A collection of available styles and their results can be found here: [BibTeX and bibliography](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.html)

If you don't find a suitable style and you want to use BibTeX you can create your own style by using [`custom-bib`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) which is also compatible with `natbib`.

The second and most recommend method is the usage of [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex). You can use a style provided by the package itself or you use a [contributed style](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib). The question/answer of 
[Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) helps you for the first step.